# How select data from same table with different status in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this [image: my table].

I want to select random 10 non fancy suite_number
and random 10 fancy suite_number. Now am using two query to do this.
 Can i do it with one query?
How select data from same table with different status in mysql?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
( SELECT suite_number 
    FROM tbl_name
   WHERE is_fancy = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL
( SELECT suite_number 
    FROM tbl_name
   WHERE is_fancy = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

The last line `ORDER BY RAND()` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT suite_number
FROM my_table
WHERE is_fancy = '1'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT suite_number
FROM my_table
WHERE is_fancy = '0'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```